# How to implement an "uninterruptible sleep" function?

Tags: android, daemon

My purpose is to implement a daemon process, in Android, which could not be killed.

I did some studies and found out the only possible way without root permission is to make the daemon process uninterruptible. And disk I/O operations, especially for NFS server, is most likely to cause a uninterruptible sleep.

But mounting an NFS server without root permission is impossible in Android. So I'm currently stuck here. Could I just use read/write calls to trigger a uninterruptible sleep? Or could anybody please give a successful example?

I know unkillable process is annoying. It's just for case studies.

Comment: what NFS are you referring to?

Comment: @pskink I'm using the Servers ultimate, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimate, from google play to set up a local NFS server in my Android devices. Then I tried to mount it but failed, due to no root permission

Comment: what does NFS have to do with "uninterruptible sleep" ?

Comment: Stopping the NFS server while the client is accessing the NFS server will make the client process uninterruptible sleep

Answer (score 0):

Pity that finally I found it's impossible to make the daemon unkillable through uninterruptible sleep. Because all the other interruptible threads will be killed by SIGKILL and uninterruptible thread is blocked so that I can do nothing in it.